# Как получить список MAC-адресов в ЛВС на C#?

Tags: c#, .net, сеть

Мне нужно получить список MAC-адресов всех компьютеров в ЛВС. Как я могу это сделать?
  Думаю, что можно получить этот список у DHCP-сервера, но не могу понять, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Источник codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/358946/Retrieving-IP-and-MAC-addresses-for-a-LAN)

Для получения используем код:

```
// Получить мой IP-адрес компьютера
Console.WriteLine("My IP : {0}", GetIPAddress());
// Получить мой MAC-адрес компьютера
Console.WriteLine("My MAC: {0}", GetMacAddress());
// Получить все устройства в сети
Dictionary<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress> all = GetAllDevicesOnLAN();

foreach (KeyValuePair<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress> kvp in all)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IP : {0}\n MAC {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Для его работы следующие структуру и методы:

```
/// <summary>
/// MIB_IPNETROW cтруктура возвращаемая GetIpNetTable
/// НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ ЭТУ СТРУКТУРУ.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MIB_IPNETROW
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwIndex;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwPhysAddrLen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte mac0;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte mac1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte mac2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte mac3;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte mac4;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte mac5;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte mac6;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte mac7;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwAddr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwType;
}

/// <summary>
/// GetIpNetTable Внешний метод
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pIpNetTable"></param>
/// <param name="pdwSize"></param>
/// <param name="bOrder"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[DllImport("IpHlpApi.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
static extern int GetIpNetTable(IntPtr pIpNetTable,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref int pdwSize, bool bOrder);

/// <summary>
/// Коды ошибок GetIpNetTable возвращает, что мы распознаем
/// </summary>
const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
/// <summary>
/// Получить IP-адреса и MAC-адреса всех известных устройств в локальной сети.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// 1) Эта таблица не обновляется часто - выбор из неё ​​может занять некоторое время 
///    , чтобы выявить, что устройство пропало из сети или новое устройство было подключено. 
/// 2) Фильтрует не локальные устройства, если они найдены - это многоадресная рассылка
///    и могут быть исключены по диапазону IP-адресов.        
/// </remarks>
/// <returns></returns>
private static Dictionary<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress> GetAllDevicesOnLAN()
{
    Dictionary<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress> all = new Dictionary<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress>();
    // Добавляем этот компьютер в список ... 
    all.Add(GetIPAddress(), GetMacAddress());
    int spaceForNetTable = 0;
    // Получаем необходимое пространство     
    // Мы делаем это, запрашивая таблицу, но не указывая никакого пространства вообще.
    // Возвращаемое значение скажет нам, сколько нам действительно нужно.
    GetIpNetTable(IntPtr.Zero, ref spaceForNetTable, false);
    // Распределяем пространство     
    // Мы используем блок try-finally для обеспечения выполнения.
    IntPtr rawTable = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        rawTable = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(spaceForNetTable);
        // Получаем фактические данные
        int errorCode = GetIpNetTable(rawTable, ref spaceForNetTable, false);
        if (errorCode != 0)
        {
            // Сбой по какой-то причине - здесь больше ничего нельзя сделать.
            throw new Exception(string.Format(
              "Unable to retrieve network table. Error code {0}", errorCode));
        }
        // Получаем количество строк
        int rowsCount = Marshal.ReadInt32(rawTable);
        IntPtr currentBuffer = new IntPtr(rawTable.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Int32)));
        // Конвертируем необработанную таблицу в отдельные записи
        MIB_IPNETROW[] rows = new MIB_IPNETROW[rowsCount];
        for (int index = 0; index < rowsCount; index++)
        {
            rows[index] = (MIB_IPNETROW)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(currentBuffer.ToInt64() +
                                        (index * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIB_IPNETROW)))
                                       ),
                                        typeof(MIB_IPNETROW));
        }
        // Определяем список фиктивных записей (мы можем их отбросить)
        PhysicalAddress virtualMAC = new PhysicalAddress(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
        PhysicalAddress broadcastMAC = new PhysicalAddress(new byte[] { 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255 });
        foreach (MIB_IPNETROW row in rows)
        {
            IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(BitConverter.GetBytes(row.dwAddr));
            byte[] rawMAC = new byte[] { row.mac0, row.mac1, row.mac2, row.mac3, row.mac4, row.mac5 };
            PhysicalAddress pa = new PhysicalAddress(rawMAC);
            if (!pa.Equals(virtualMAC) && !pa.Equals(broadcastMAC) && !IsMulticast(ip))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("IP: {0}\t\tMAC: {1}", ip.ToString(), pa.ToString());
                if (!all.ContainsKey(ip))
                {
                    all.Add(ip, pa);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Освобождаем память
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(rawTable);
    }
    return all;
}

/// <summary>
/// Получает IP-адрес текущего ПК
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private static IPAddress GetIPAddress()
{
    String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
    IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
    IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
    foreach (IPAddress ip in addr)
    {
        if (!ip.IsIPv6LinkLocal)
        {
            return (ip);
        }
    }
    return addr.Length > 0 ? addr[0] : null;
}

/// <summary>
/// Получает MAC-адрес текущего ПК.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private static PhysicalAddress GetMacAddress()
{
    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        // Учитывть только сетевые интерфейсы Ethernet
        if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet &&
            nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            return nic.GetPhysicalAddress();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/// <summary>
/// Метод возвращает "истина", если указанный IP-адрес является адресом многоадресной рассылки
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ip"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static bool IsMulticast(IPAddress ip)
{
    bool result = true;
    if (!ip.IsIPv6Multicast)
    {
        byte highIP = ip.GetAddressBytes()[0];
        if (highIP < 224 || highIP > 239)
        {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```