# Как считать подключенные IP адреса с локальной сети?

Tags: c#, lan

Нужно считать, или проще говоря проверить, кто подключен к локальной сети, и узнать IP адреса подключенных компьютеров, но так чтобы допустим запускаем программу проверялись все IP адреса и узнать, когда они вышли или подключены.

```
public void GetLocalAddress() 
{ 
// доступно ли сетевое подключение 
if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) 
return; 
// запросить у DNS-сервера IP-адрес, связанный с именем узла 
var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()); 
// Пройдем по списку IP-адресов, связанных с узлом 
foreach (var ip in host.AddressList) 
{ 
// если текущий IP-адрес версии IPv4, то выведем его 
if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) 
{ 
Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString()); 
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: тогда вам надо открыть сырой сокет (raw socket) и мониторить весь проходящий трафик и доставать из него интересующую информацию. особое внимание обратите на arp запросы. А чот бы знать кто когда подключился или отключился, ваша программа должна быть запущена постоянно и сама фиксировать появление запросов от новых компов и по таймаутам фиксировать что какие то из них исчезли

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, что такое "подключенные IP адреса с локальной сети". Если имеются в виду адреса компьютеров в текущем домене / рабочей группе NetBIOS, их можно получить с помощью функции *NetServerEnum*:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsTest1
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512242/find-all-computers-on-network-using-netserverenum */

        [DllImport("Netapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int NetServerEnum(
            string serverName,
            int dwLevel,
            ref IntPtr pBuf,
            int dwPrefMaxLen,
            out int dwEntriesRead,
            out int dwTotalEntries,
            int dwServerType,
            string domain,
            out int dwResumeHandle
            );

        [DllImport("Netapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr pBuf);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct ServerInfo100
        {
            internal int sv100_platform_id;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            internal string sv100_name;
        }        

        public static List<string> GetNetworkComputers(string domain = null) 
        {
            List<string> networkComputers = new List<string>();
            const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;
            int SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION = 1;
            int SV_TYPE_SERVER = 2;
            IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tmpBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            int entriesRead;
            int totalEntries;
            int resHandle;
            int sizeofInfo = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ServerInfo100));
            string elem;

            try
            {
                int ret = NetServerEnum(null, 100, ref buffer,
                                        MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out entriesRead, out totalEntries,
                                        SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION | SV_TYPE_SERVER, domain, out resHandle);

                if (ret == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalEntries; i++)
                    {
                        tmpBuffer = new IntPtr((long)buffer + (i * sizeofInfo));

                        ServerInfo100 svrInfo = (ServerInfo100)
                                                   Marshal.PtrToStructure(tmpBuffer,
                                                                          typeof(ServerInfo100));

                        elem = svrInfo.sv100_name;

                        try
                        {
                            IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(svrInfo.sv100_name);
                            IPAddress ip = ips.First();

                            if (ip != null) elem += ": " + ip.ToString();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            elem += " " + ex.Message;
                        }

                        networkComputers.Add(elem);
                    }
                }
            }            
            finally
            {
                NetApiBufferFree(buffer);
            }
            return networkComputers;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                        
        }       

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var list = GetNetworkComputers();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            foreach (var s in list)
            {
                textBox1.Text += s + Environment.NewLine;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

IP-адреса для компьютеров, с которыми недавно взаимодействовал текущий компьютер, можно получить из ARP-кэша, как в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642646/240512).

Если подразумеваются все адреса в пределах какой-либо IP-подсети, можно сделать это только сканированием всех адресов. Для этого нужно сначала определить условие существование адреса: это может быть наличие для него имени в обратном DNS, прохождение пинга, наличие на каком-либо порту сервера, принимающего входящие соединения и т.п. (выберите то условие, которое имеет смысл в вашем окружении). Например, определим метод для проверки наличия информации по IP-адресу в обратном DNS:

```
//метод проверки существования IP-адреса
static async Task<bool> CheckIp(IPAddress x)
{ 
    var task = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
    {
        string res = "";
        try
        {
            var entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(x); //получаем информацию из обратного DNS
            if (entry.HostName != null && entry.HostName != "") res = (entry.HostName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            res = "";
        }
        return res != "";
    });
    return await task;            
}
```

Тогда просканировать все адреса в IPv4-cети можно как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsTest1
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                        
        }

        static void IncrementIp(ref uint x)
        {
            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
            uint y = BitConverter.ToUInt32(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0] },0);
            y++;
            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(y);
            x = BitConverter.ToUInt32(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0] }, 0);
        }

        static int IpCompare(uint x, uint y)
        {
            if (x == y) return 0;

            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
            uint xx = BitConverter.ToUInt32(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0] }, 0);

            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(y);
            uint yy = BitConverter.ToUInt32(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0] }, 0);

            if (xx < yy) return -1;
            else return 1;
        }                

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            IPAddress net = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.100.0"); //адрес подсети
            IPAddress mask = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0"); //маска подсети

            uint x1 = (uint)net.Address; //начальный адрес подсети           
            uint x2 = (uint)(~mask.Address | net.Address); //конечный адрес подсети

            textBox1.Text = "";

            //сканирование IP-адресов
            IncrementIp(ref x1);
            for(uint i = x1; IpCompare(i,x2)<0; IncrementIp(ref i))
            {
                IPAddress ip = new IPAddress((long)i);

                bool res = await CheckIp(ip);

                if (res)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += ip.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            } 
        }
    }      
}
```

Определить время подключения и отключения компьютеров можно только периодическим сканированием с сохранением результатов и сравнением их с предыдущими сканированиями.