# В списке локальных сетевых интерфейсов отображается только loopback

Tags: c#, .net

Пытаюсь получить список сетевых интерфейсов, чтобы в дальнейшем с помощью него послать ARP-запрос в сеть.
Использую библиотеку sharppcap

Проблема заключается в том, что в списке отображается исключительно один интерфейс - loopback. Как мне получить полный список интерфейсов, соответствующий реальности?

Код C#

```
    //Получаем список устройств
    devices = LibPcapLiveDeviceList.Instance;

    //Если устройств нет - выводим ошибку, заканчиваем работу
    if (devices.Count < 1) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Сетевые устройства не найдены", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    //Если дошли сюда, устройства есть, выведем их список в ListBox (listDevicesLocal)
    int i = 0; //Идентификатор

    foreach (var device in devices)
    {
        listDevicesLocal.Items.Add(i + ": " + device.Name + " (" + device.Description + ")");
        i++;
    }
```

[image: Список сетевых интерфейсов, который был получен]

Comment: Может быть, вам нужен метод [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: В таком случае возникнет проблема с Sharppcap.Arp, который принимает в качестве интерфейса объект класса LibPcapLiveDevice

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, для чего вы это делаете?

Comment: Пытаюсь разработать приложение, которое будет отображать список устройств в локальной сети и их вендоров с помощью декомпозиции MAC-адресов

Comment: Т.е. вам нужно получить MAC-адреса всех устройств в локальной сети?

Comment: Да, планировал использовать ARP-запрос для этой цели

Comment: С ходу не нашел решения. Можно попробовать выполнить команду `arp -a` в командной строке и распарсить результат ее выполнения. У вас в итоге окажутся пары "ip — mac-адрес".

Comment: Либо еще один вариант - **пропинговать** все возможные ip-адреса внутри сети (чтобы обновить ARP-таблицу), после чего **прочитать ARP-таблицу** через низкоуровневые функции ОС. Но этот вариант будет сложнее.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Воспользуюсь вашим советом!

Comment: Вот здесь есть пример работы с ARP-таблицей: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642646/240512